# Formating text + creating elements with JQ

Tags: jquery

I have two pieces of jquery code, they work perfectly separate, but together - no.

Basicaly, there is code that generates textareas (with different id's), and code that allows text in textareas to be formated. When text in textarea is bolded, it needs to stay like that, when i generate second textarea, and bold it, it need to stay bolded as well. Here it is:

```
<button id="bold">B</button>
<button id="add_txt">Add txtarea</button> 

<div id="vk_main">


</div>

var c = 0;
$.activeEl = $();

$('#add_txt').on('click', function() {
    var $div = $('<textarea id="ta_' + (c) + '">Text here.</textarea>');
    $('#vk_main').append($div);
});

$("textarea").focus(function() {
    $.activeEl = $(this);
});

$("#bold").click(function() {
    $("textarea").css("font-weight", "");
    $.activeEl.css("font-weight", "bold");
});
```

WORKING EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyNT/qhjJs/

Comment: Post your code here; JS Fiddle, like *any* external site, can be used for demos or reference, but if, in this case, JS Fiddle falls over (again...) your external resource limits the use of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$("textarea").live("focus",function() {
   $.activeEl = $(this);
});

$("#bold").click(function() {
    $.activeEl.css("font-weight", "bold");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qhjJs/5/

Comment: Works, but when i create another textarea, and bold text inside of it, first textarea becomes "unbolded" (and also cant be bolded again) :(

Comment: it will always bold the font of last textarea

Comment: well, it need to bold textarea and leave it bolded, if you understand what i want to say

Answer (score 4):

If your change the style of text area which have focus then try this [http://jsfiddle.net/qhjJs/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/qhjJs/6/)

Comment: No, i want change to be permanent, formating need t ostay after changing focus.

Comment: please check again i added the permenet class "fontWeight" and add the style in that class link is http://jsfiddle.net/qhjJs/6/

Answer (score 3):

You have a scoping problem on the `activeEl` variable. Try putting it on some namespace, like the jQuery object instead:

```
var c = 0;
$.activeEl = $();

$('#add_txt').on('click', function() {
    var $div = $('<textarea id="ta_' + (c) + '">Text here.</textarea>');
    $('#vk_main').append($div);
});

$("textarea").focus(function() {
    $.activeEl = $(this);
});

$("#bold").click(function() {
    $("textarea").css("font-weight", "");
    $.activeEl.css("font-weight", "bold");
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time of binding focus event for textarea, that element will not be present.

You should do this:

```
$("textarea").live('focus', function() {
    activeEl = $(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YqvWg/

Comment: Well, same answer as for one of previous suggestions: Works, but when i create another textarea, and bold text inside of it, first textarea becomes "unbolded" (and also cant be bolded again)